# PhantomJS order iframe

Tags: iframe, phantomjs

How can I get the iframes on the page? I want to get an external options(width, height, id, src) and inner HTML.

It's all I can get only if the iframes on the page are not dynamically added. If they are dynamically added, the order of the IFRAME in the DOM and in the frameid (switchToFrame(frameid)) differs, and I can not compare them.

**HTML**:

```
<iframe src="iframe.php?id=1"></iframe>
<iframe src="iframe.php?id=2"></iframe>
<div id="dynamic_iframe"></div>
<div id="dynamic_iframe2"></div>
<iframe src="iframe.php?id=3"></iframe>

<script>
    var el = document.createElement("iframe");
    el.src = 'iframe.php?id=21';
    document.getElementById('dynamic_iframe').appendChild(el);

    var el = document.createElement("iframe");
    el.src = 'iframe.php?id=22';
    document.getElementById('dynamic_iframe2').appendChild(el);
</script>
```

**PhantomJS**:

```
getAllIFramesFromPage = function(page){
return page.evaluate(function() {
        var matches = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
        ifames = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i){
            ifames.push(matches[i].src);
        }
        return ifames;
    });        
};
```

**out**:

```
iframe.php?id=1
iframe.php?id=2
iframe.php?id=21
iframe.php?id=22
iframe.php?id=3
```

**PhantomJS**:

```
var cnt = page.framesCount;
for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
    page.switchToFrame(i);
    console.log(page.framePlainText);
    page.switchToMainFrame();
}
```

**out**:

```
1
2
3
21
22
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here. You seem to be able to get the iframe (contents) from the page. Are you asking why the two methods produce a different ordering? If so, then this has probably something to do with intricacies of PhantomJS and only developers could give you some answer. How do you want to compare the iframes?

Comment: I need to compare all the iframes in the DOM with their page.frameContent.

**for example:**

    <iframe src="iframe.php?id=3" width="100px">text</iframe>

I want to get "100px" and "text".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get out of a problem like this:
When I pass all the iframe into the DOM I put in them hidden value

```
page.switchToMainFrame();
page.evaluate(function() {
    var matches = document.querySelectorAll('iframe');
    ifames = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < matches.length; ++i){
        var iframeWindow = matches[i].contentWindow || matches[i].contentDocument.parent;
        var frmBody = iframeWindow.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].frame_id = i;
    }
});
```

Already inside an iframe I can get this value as follows:

```
var cnt = this.page.framesCount;
for(var i = 0; i < cnt; i++){
    page.switchToFrame(i);
    frameIndex = this.page.evaluate(function() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].frame_id !== undefined){
            return document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].frame_id;
        }
        return false;
    });
    this.page.switchToParentFrame();
}
```

Comment: thank you! thats great for getting frame by id (not the same as frame_id)